# FFMPEG file reduction size error

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg version 0.8.21-6:0.8.21-0+deb7u1

Below is my code.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -crf 28 -vcodec -c copy upload/new_video.mp4
```

Below is my Error

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'copy'
```

Comment: What you were using is not `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg. That's the fake, dead "`ffmpeg`" from the Libav fork. You can [download a recent, real `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and optionally put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c copy -c:v libx264 -crf 28 upload/new_video.mp4
```

but upgrade ffmpeg. Your version is ancient.